# Get notification when app is in background mode

Tags: swift, background, notifications, push-notification, background-process

I want to call a function when I receive a notification, even when my application is in background

I found a lot of question / answer on stackoverflow
but in me it does not. So I will explain everything I 've done

i have background mode activate

[here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=685641Capturedcran20150914120646.png)

my info.plist is good

[here](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=478060Capturedcran20150914120732.png)

in my didFinishLaunchingWithOption i have

```
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Badge | .Sound | .Alert, categories: nil))
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

and i have

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    println("NOTIFICATION 4");
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    println("NOTIFICATION FETCH");
}
```

but i can't see my log when i send my notification

my notification is send like this

```
    { deviceToken: XXXXX,
    expiration: 1442225011,
    identifier: 0,
    payload: 
    { 'content-available': '1',
    aps: { badge: 0, alert: 'Hello' } } }
```

I do not know what to do more ... I really can not receive this notification, nothing happens ( I receive the banner but no call to my function)

thank's a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in documents:

> The aps dictionary can also contain the content-available property. The content-available property with a value of 1 lets the remote notification act as a “silent” notification.

so you should insert content-available in aps dictionary, like this:

```
{ deviceToken: XXXXX,
expiration: 1442225011,
identifier: 0,
payload: 
{ aps: { 'content-available': '1', badge: 0, alert: 'Hello' } } }
```

Comment: Thank's it's ok ! but... other question. I want run timer when i receive notification. but he don't call timer ... how i can do ? thank's

Comment: you have a 30 sec or less (i think) window to run every code that is necessary to do and fetch data. there is no way to keep app running as I know. You may need to change architecture in this case.